# AS3 - Replace portion of string with a variable string

Tags: regex, arrays, string, actionscript-3

Trying to replace a portion of a string with a "-" if it matches a string variable in AS3.

```
var re:RegExp = new RegExp(imageArray[j][1],"gi");
trace(imageArray[jTemp][2].replace(re,"-"));
```

imageArray[jTemp][2] is a string
imageArray[j][1] is a string as well
I'm not getting the result I expect. I would like trace above to return 'permanentContainer-' Here are the traces for the above variables

```
permanentContainer-temporaryContainer-
temporaryContainer
```

Comment: So, what is the unexpected result you're getting? Your code above _should_ output
`permanentContainer---`

Comment: It looks like I needed to assign the strings in my array to specific string variables. The minute I did that, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str:String = "permanentContainer-temporaryContainer-"
var pattern:RegExp = /-[(a-z)]+-/i;
var re:RegExp = new RegExp( "-^-$", "i");
trace( str.replace(pattern,"-"));

// traces
// permanentConta1iner-
```

Comment: Ok. That solved my question, but I guess my question was not correct. I will rephrase in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what ended up working for me:

```
var str:String=imageArray[jTemp][2];
var pattern:String=imageArray[j][1];
var regex:RegExp=new RegExp(pattern,"ig");
imageArray[jTemp][2]=str.replace(regex,"-");
```